# Replace a word in string if it is found in an array

Tags: java, arrays, substring

For example the user types: The fruit apple is my favourite.
I'd like to return: The fruit ***** is my favourite.

But my code only returns the first word.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Type someting: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = scan.next();

    String [] myArray = {"apple", "banana", "strawberry"}; 
    boolean matchFound = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        if (s.toLowerCase().contains(myArray[i].toLowerCase())){
            String beep = String.join("", Collections.nCopies(myArray[i].length(), "*"));
            String result = s.replaceAll(myArray[i].toLowerCase(), beep);
            System.out.println(result);

            matchFound = true;
        }

    }

    if (matchFound == false){
        System.out.println(s);
    }


}
```

Comment: Why do you print it if there is no match found?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Way of inputting is not correct

It should be

```
String s = scan.nextLine();
```

rather than scan.next();

With s = scan.next();

s will only get initialized as "The"

Comment: What an easy solution. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also put a break once you found the element. This will make sure to come out of the loop when element is found and improve the code performance.

```
matchFound = true;
break;
```

Comment: Actually I want to check every element, and if found change that(s) as well.

Comment: Are you saying 'myArray' can have duplicate of fruits? If Yes, no need to put break. if no duplicate, then break will be good to have. Because if you found a element, then next time you wont get it.

Comment: I mean if the user types two or more words that are equal to one of in the array then I want to replace those with * as well.